# How can i open the app by clicking on the notification, not by setting the id to the default in pressAction but in notifee.onBackgroundEvent

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

i want to open my app while handling the event 'notifee.onBackgroundEvent' not by setting
id to default in pressAction

```
notifee.onBackgroundEvent(async ({ type, detail }) => {
    if (type === EventType.ACTION_PRESS && detail.pressAction.id === 'accept') {
        await notifee.cancelNotification(detail.notification.id);
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('called', 'true');
        console.log('accepted');
    }
    else if (type === EventType.ACTION_PRESS && detail.pressAction.id === 'decline') {
        await notifee.cancelNotification(detail.notification.id);
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('called', 'false');
        console.log('declined');
    }
});
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

i figure it out, if we want to open app and also want to register event with it, we can do it by passing id 'default' in pressAction, it will open the app and you can listen to this event on your code like this, change pressAction.id from accept to default

```
notifee.onBackgroundEvent(async ({ type, detail }) => {
if (type === EventType.ACTION_PRESS && detail.pressAction.id === 'accept') {
    await notifee.cancelNotification(detail.notification.id);
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('called', 'true');
    console.log('accepted');
}
```

});